# Get contents of specific tags in XML using elemettree

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

Following is my XML data:

```
<PubmedArticle>
<MedlineCitation Status="MEDLINE" Owner="NLM">
  <PMID Version="1">1883738</PMID>
  <DateCompleted>
    <Year>1991</Year>
    <Month>10</Month>
    <Day>07</Day>
  </DateCompleted>
  <DateRevised>
    <Year>2013</Year>
    <Month>11</Month>
    <Day>21</Day>
  </DateRevised>
  <Article PubModel="Print">
    <Journal>
      <ISSN IssnType="Print">0959-9673</ISSN>
      <JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
        <Volume>72</Volume>
        <Issue>4</Issue>
        <PubDate>
          <Year>1991</Year>
          <Month>Aug</Month>
        </PubDate>
      </JournalIssue>
      <Title>International journal of experimental pathology</Title>
      <ISOAbbreviation>Int J Exp Pathol</ISOAbbreviation>
    </Journal>
    <ArticleTitle>The effect of HeNe laser radiation on the thyroid gland of the rat.</ArticleTitle>
    <Pagination>
      <MedlinePgn>379-85</MedlinePgn>
    </Pagination>
    <Abstract>
      <AbstractText>Although laser irradiation is becoming common practice in medicine, there is not always a clear understanding of the possible side-effects. The present report is a light and electron microscopic study of the effects of fixed low intensity doses of soft HeNe laser on the thyroid of Wistar rats. The immediate effects are mild multifocal degenerative changes; these lesions recover in less than 3 months. Long-term lesions are identified only by electron microscopy; they consist of an increased number of peroxisomes and free or intramitochondrial crystalline structures. We discuss the laser's hypothetical functions.</AbstractText>
    </Abstract>
    <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Lerma</LastName>
        <ForeName>E</ForeName>
        <Initials>E</Initials>
        <AffiliationInfo>
          <Affiliation>Department of Pathology and Radiology, Hospital Universitario Virgen Macarena, University of Seville, Spain.</Affiliation>
        </AffiliationInfo>
      </Author>
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Hevia</LastName>
        <ForeName>A</ForeName>
        <Initials>A</Initials>
      </Author>
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Rodrigo</LastName>
        <ForeName>P</ForeName>
        <Initials>P</Initials>
      </Author>
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Gonzalez-Campora</LastName>
        <ForeName>R</ForeName>
        <Initials>R</Initials>
      </Author>
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Armas</LastName>
        <ForeName>J R</ForeName>
        <Initials>JR</Initials>
      </Author>
      <Author ValidYN="Y">
        <LastName>Galera</LastName>
        <ForeName>H</ForeName>
        <Initials>H</Initials>
      </Author>
    </AuthorList>
    <Language>eng</Language>
    <PublicationTypeList>
      <PublicationType UI="D016428">Journal Article</PublicationType>
    </PublicationTypeList>
  </Article>
  <MedlineJournalInfo>
    <Country>England</Country>
    <MedlineTA>Int J Exp Pathol</MedlineTA>
    <NlmUniqueID>9014042</NlmUniqueID>
    <ISSNLinking>0959-9673</ISSNLinking>
  </MedlineJournalInfo>
  <ChemicalList>
    <Chemical>
      <RegistryNumber>06LU7C9H1V</RegistryNumber>
      <NameOfSubstance UI="D014284">Triiodothyronine</NameOfSubstance>
    </Chemical>
    <Chemical>
      <RegistryNumber>Q51BO43MG4</RegistryNumber>
      <NameOfSubstance UI="D013974">Thyroxine</NameOfSubstance>
    </Chemical>
  </ChemicalList>
  <CitationSubset>IM</CitationSubset>
  <CommentsCorrectionsList>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>J Histochem Cytochem. 1969 Oct;17(10):675-80</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">4194356</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>Acta Anat (Basel). 1986;125(1):10-3</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">3953239</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>Anat Anz. 1977;142(3):209-12</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">603070</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>J Cell Biol. 1964 Nov;23:383-5</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">14222822</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>J Cell Biol. 1967 Jun;33(3):605-23</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">6036524</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>Am J Med. 1983 May;74(5):852-62</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">6837608</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
    <CommentsCorrections RefType="Cites">
      <RefSource>Exp Eye Res. 1977 Jan;24(1):45-56</RefSource>
      <PMID Version="1">402283</PMID>
    </CommentsCorrections>
  </CommentsCorrectionsList>
  <MeshHeadingList>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D000818" MajorTopicYN="N">Animals</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D007834" MajorTopicYN="N">Lasers</DescriptorName>
      <QualifierName UI="Q000009" MajorTopicYN="Y">adverse effects</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D008297" MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D008830" MajorTopicYN="N">Microbodies</DescriptorName>
      <QualifierName UI="Q000528" MajorTopicYN="N">radiation effects</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D008854" MajorTopicYN="N">Microscopy, Electron</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D051381" MajorTopicYN="N">Rats</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D011919" MajorTopicYN="N">Rats, Inbred Strains</DescriptorName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D013961" MajorTopicYN="N">Thyroid Gland</DescriptorName>
      <QualifierName UI="Q000528" MajorTopicYN="Y">radiation effects</QualifierName>
      <QualifierName UI="Q000648" MajorTopicYN="N">ultrastructure</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D013974" MajorTopicYN="N">Thyroxine</DescriptorName>
      <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
    <MeshHeading>
      <DescriptorName UI="D014284" MajorTopicYN="N">Triiodothyronine</DescriptorName>
      <QualifierName UI="Q000097" MajorTopicYN="N">blood</QualifierName>
    </MeshHeading>
  </MeshHeadingList>
  <OtherID Source="NLM">PMC2001961</OtherID>
</MedlineCitation>
<PubmedData>
```

I need to extract all the Author LastName from the document. However, there are multiple such files each of them having varied Author name. How can I parse through this file and extract only the Author LastName into a list to create a database?

I have used elementtree to parse the document. Following is my code:

```
tree = ET.parse("file path"+file)
            doc = tree.getroot()
            for LastName in doc.iter('LastName'):
                file1 = (ET.tostring(LastName, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
                file2 = file1[48:(len(file1))]
                author_name_lastname = file2.split("<")[0]
                print(author_name_lastname)
```

Here I can only print the first Author name "Lerma".

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from lxml import etree as ET

DIR="D:\yourfilesdirectory/"

for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        with open(file=DIR+filename,mode='r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
            _tree = ET.fromstring(text=file.read())
            _all_metadata_tags = _tree.xpath('.//LastName')
            for i in _all_metadata_tags:
                print(i.text + '\n')

    else:
        print("skipping for filename")
```

Comment: I actually have 100+ files from which I need to parse and then extract the Author LastName. All of these files are in a file in my computer. When I try this, I get the following error:
    parser.feed(text)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'

Following is the code:
 tree = ET.parse("file Path")
                doc = tree.getroot()
                _tree= ET.fromstring(doc)
                _all_metadata_tags = _tree.xpath('.//LastName')
                for i in _all_metadata_tags:
                    print(i.text + '\n')

Comment: edited my solution according to your request. please note i m using python 3.5 and windows